# Select the oldest records in a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

please, how can I select the oldest records in a table in oracle? and if it is possible to show them by date. 
Thank you

Comment: Is there a `date` or `timestamp` column?

Comment: In addition to Ypercube's obvious question ;)   if you can provide/create a small working sample (ie table with 5 or 6 rows and a few columns relevant to you ??)  we could work on that much easier ;)

Comment: Do you have Flashback Data Archive enabled?

Comment: *select the oldest records in a table* Oldest - by insertion or by last edition? Does the column which contains the timestamp of the last action in interest exists in the table structure? If no, and the action in interest is insertion - does the autoincrement column exists?

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration, the table in question does not have any colum with dates, timestamp ... neither autoincrementales ... it would be something like for example: columns Name1 Name2 Age Salary only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not, itself, track the date a row is inserted into a table. So unless you yourself *design* the table with something like a DATE_INSERTED column, *and* reigorously enforce the proper population of that column, then the answer to "how can I select the oldest records in a table in oracle?" is "you can't".

Answer (score 2):

First Rule of Relational Databases - Rows in a Table have *no intrinsic order*.

If you want to know when a record was added or updated, then you need to keep track of that for yourself.